# ncbi-blast: not found

Tags: debian, software-installation, docker

I got `ncbi-blast: not found` despite it should be there (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/ncbi-blast+/download)

```
FROM debian:jessie
# based on https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/5.6/jessie/apache/Dockerfile

RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libapache2-mod-perl2 \
        libcgi-pm-perl \
        php5-cgi \
        php5-mysql \
        libapache2-mod-php5 \
        php5-mysql \
        php5-gd && \
        ncbi-blast+ && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Remove the && from `php5-gd && \ ncbi-blast+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Mark Plotnick commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451877/ncbi-blast-not-found#comment820657_451877), it appears you rearranged the lines at some point, adding the line for `ncbi-blast+` after `pgp5-gd`, but you forgot to remove the `&&` at the end of `php5-gd` so that the next continuation line lists another package instead of ending the previous command. The command as you had it would have requested installation of the packages up until `php5-gd`, after which it would have tried to *execute* `ncbi-blast+`, which presumably wasn't already installed, and so would have thrown an error, after which it would *not* have run the `rm` command. Use the following, instead:

```
RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libapache2-mod-perl2 \
        libcgi-pm-perl \
        php5-cgi \
        php5-mysql \
        libapache2-mod-php5 \
        php5-mysql \
        php5-gd \
        ncbi-blast+ && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```